# Returning nth lowest number without using built-in functions - Python

Tags: python, list

I am working on the following:
**Write a function that returns nth lowest number of a list (or iterable in general). Return the lowest if second argument not specified
Note that if a list contains duplicates, they should be handled before determining nth lowest**

I got the following to work fine:

```
numbers = [8,9, 1,300,5, 54, 54]
def nth_lowest(b, n='N/A'):
    nums = set(b)
    if n == 'N/A':
        return min(b)
    else:
        nums = sorted(nums)
        return nums[n-1]

print(nth_lowest(numbers))
print(nth_lowest('ananasgnasgzynrmas', 6))
print(nth_lowest(numbers, 4))
```

But I wanted to try to write it without using those built-in SET or MIN functions.  Here is what I have:

```
numbers = [8,9, 1,300,5, 54, 54]
def nth_lowest(b, n='N/A'):
    nums = []
    new_list = []
    for i in b:  # instead of using set()
        if i not in nums:
            nums.append(i)
    nums = sorted(nums)
    if n == 'N/A':
        while b: # instead of using min()
            minimum = b[0]
            for x in b:
                if x < minimum:
                    minimum = x
            new_list.append(minimum)
            b.remove(minimum)
        return new_list
    else:
        return nums[n-1]

print(nth_lowest(numbers))
print(nth_lowest('ananasgnasgzynrmas', 6))
print(nth_lowest(numbers, 4))
```

but it is error'ing out on the following:

```
return nums[n-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know this isn't really what you're asking about, but there's not actually any need for a special case using `min` (or equivalent) when the second argument isn't passed. Just use `1` as the default `n` value, and the rest of the code should just work.

Comment: I am curious how that would work, if I use 1 as the default.  What if the list itself didn't have a 1 in it?  What if the min value of the list was 35 or something like that? Wouldn't I still need to figure out the min() of what's in the list?

Comment: But `n` isn't supposed to be a number *in* the list, it's the ordinal of the minimum you're supposed to get, isn't it? You might want a sanity check, as there's no sense in trying to find the `-2`'th smallest number, nor the 3000th number in a list with only 10 values. But you probably want those checks *anyway* for the case you're solving by sorting and indexing. No need for the default to be a special case.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, makes sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you modify your input list during the algorithm: `b.remove(minimum)`. Then, when you use `numbers` for the second time, it is actually empty and so is `nums`. You can add the following to the top of the function to create a copy of the input:

```
b = [x for x in b]
```

Comment: thank you, that solved it.  Obvious miss on my part and makes perfect sense.  I will accept this answer when it lets me (5 mins or so).  thanks!

Comment: Note that `b[:]`, `list(b)` or `b.copy()` are probably more natural ways of shallow copying a list, rather than using a list comprehension.

Comment: @Blckknght You're right and in any case they are more performant.